# For an adiabatic gas turbine, is it possible to show that the exergetic efficiency is always greater than the isentropic efficency?

Tags: thermodynamics

Assuming the turbine is in steady state and the gas is an ideal gas with constant specific heats(perfect gas), I have reduced the problem to the following inequality[$T_0$ as known]:

$$\eta_{isentropic}\hspace{3mm} =? \hspace{3mm}   \eta_{exergetic} \\$$

$$w_{actual}/h_{1}-h_{2s}\hspace{3mm} =?\hspace{3mm} w_{actual}/h_1-h_2-T_0(s_1-s_2)$$

$$h_{1}-h_{2s}\hspace{3mm} =? \hspace{3mm} h_1 - h_2 -T_0(s_1 - s_2)$$

$$T_0(s_1-s_2)\hspace{3mm} =? \hspace{3mm} h_{2s} - h_2$$

$$T_0\left(C_v \ln\left(\frac{T_1}{T_2}\right)-R\ln\left(\frac{{P}_1}{P_2}\right)\right) \hspace{3mm} =? \hspace{3mm} C_p(T_{2s}-T_2)$$ 
$$T_0\left(C_v \ln\left(\frac{T_1}{T_2}\right)-R\ln\left(\frac{{P}_1}{P_2}\right)\right) \hspace{3mm} =? \hspace{3mm} C_p\left(T_1\left(\frac{P_1}{P_2}\right)^{(k-1)/k}-T_2\right)$$

But I don't know where to go from here; ideally I would obtain a relationship where I can change $T_0$ and see how the relationship between exergetic and isentropic efficiencies change.

Comment: I think the second formula line is wrong.

Comment: @Gert substituting in the definition of the efficiencies?